# opengl translating using utility function

Tags: opengl, translate

This is my utility function for translating points:

```
void translatePoints(float x, float y, int transX, int transY)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    // original points
    glVertex2f(x,y);    
    glVertex2f(x + transX, y + transY);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

I have similar functions for drawing a circle, scaling points and rotating points
Without using matrix translations, I have to pass the x and y values from myDisplay and make make a shape translate and scale and rotate from the center.
If I have a shape with 6 points, like a star, this function does not work.
  I guess for this function to work it has to return two points or I could use pointers. But I'm not sure how to implement either of these and I also believe I shouldn't draw these points in this function.
At the end I have to draw a scene with different shapes.

Comment: I don't see how that function translates points. It draws a line. What *exactly* do you want the function to do? Be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i think you want is

```
glVertex2f(x + transX, y + transY);
glVertex2f(a + transX, b + transY);
```

where your line goes from (x,y) to (a,b). you were drawing a line from your original point, to  your original point that was translated, instead of translating both the points.

hopefully i have interpreted your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

What I understand your question I try to explain here.
For example lets take you have drawn the 2D square using four point.Make a vairable which hold the co-ordintate value for drawing square lets assume variable name like below

```
x1, y1, z
x2, y2, z
x3, y3, z
x4, y4, z
```

Here z co-ordinate is fixed. Now if you want to make a function to translate the square then impletment your function like this.

```
void translateSquare(int transX, int transY)
{
  x1 + transX; y1 + transY;
  x2 + transX; y2 + transY;
  x3 + transX; y3 + transY;
  x4 + transX; y4 + transY;
}
```

When you call this function your square will be translated by value transX and transY. So make a function similar to like this for your display.